# What is the different between 'IsEnabled' and 'Start/Stop' of DispatcherTimer?

Tags: c#, wpf

I think that IsEnabled = false/true is equally the same with Stop/Start method of class System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
Am I right?

[EDIT]
Start()           : begin timer with a full interval countdown.
IsEnabled = false : pause the timer, the interval countdown remains.
IsEnabled = true  : resume the timer & continue with the last used interval countdown.
Stop()            : stop the timer, will the interval countdown reset?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Considering that `Start/Stop` toggles the `IsEnabled` property, your assumption is close.

`Start/Stop` differs as the `Interval` is reset, where as just toggling the `IsEnabled` will not reset the `Interval`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.start.aspx):

> Setting IsEnabled to false when the
>   timer is started stops the timer.
>
> Setting IsEnabled to true when the
>   timer is stopped starts the timer.
>
> Start sets IsEnabled to true.
>
> Start resets the timer Interval.

EDIT:
What I mean by the interval being reset is not the Interval property itself, but the background interval that determines how long until the next tick event is fired.

Eg. If you have an interval of 1000ms and you stop/disable it if with 250ms to run (it's run for 750ms), this is the result depending on how you start it again.

- If you start it with `Start()`, then the passed interval will be reset back to 0 and it will be 1000ms before the `Tick` event is raised.
- If you re-enable it with `IsEnabled = true` then it will continue from it's current location and the `Tick` event will be raised in 250ms.

I hope this clarifies it for you.

Comment: What happens with the Interval if it is reseted? At the moment, I think when calling Start/Stop, the Interval value (int) doesn't change.

Comment: Not the interval value itself, but the background interval. I've updated my answer to answer this.

Comment: Thanks! It's quite clear now except what happens when we call Stop()? Will the background interval reseted?

Comment: The reset occurs the `Start()` is called. I would surmise (although I haven't tested) that if you called `Stop()` then `IsEnabled = true` that it would just continue, rather than reset.

Comment: Perhaps the documentation says that Start resets the timer, but if you just call `Start` all the time the timeout won't be reset. You need to Stop/Start.

Comment: I just tested this and found that a Start by itself won't reset the timer. You have to stop then start to get it to reset the timer to the full interval.

Comment: This is incorrect. Both Start(), Stop() and IsEnabled = true and IsEnabled = false do the same thing. I just created a sample application where I continuously set IsEnabled to false, then back to true while a timer was running - the timer never completed. This is because whether you call IsEnabled = false or Stop(), the interval gets reset under the hood

Comment: Then answer from @antwoord also shows that it is not as stated here.

Answer (score 6):

Implementation of DispatcherTimer.IsEnabled

```
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
       get
       {
           return _isEnabled;
       }
       set
       {
           lock (_instanceLock)
           {
               if (!value && _isEnabled)
               {
                   Stop();
               }
               else
               {
                   if (!value || _isEnabled)
                       return;
                   Start();
               }
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Base/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherTimer@cs/1/DispatcherTimer@cs

Comment: Source code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherTimer.cs,81aa4c1d6752e30e