# How to pause a DispatchTimer?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to pause the timer in WP7 ? 
In my application i want to pause and resume the timer. But DispatcherTimer has only start and stop. how to pause the timer ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Define a global variable:

```
private static DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
```

Then when the Start button is pressed you make the following check to determine whether the timer has been stopped or paused:

```
private void btnStartClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dispatcherTimer == null)
    {
        this.dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        this.dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        this.dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    }

    if (this.EndTime == DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        this.EndTime = DateTime.Now + (TimeSpan)this.timeSpan.Value;
    }

    this.dispatcherTimer.Start();
}
```

Next when the Pause button is pressed you can just stop the timer, because the next time when the Start button is pressed you will pass through the check described above:

```
private void btnPauseClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.dispatcherTimer.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the IsEnabled property to false to stop it and then back to true when you want it to continue.

Answer (score 0):

For Pause/Resume functionality, you have to build that into your Tick handler, start and stop the timer.

If your timer interval is about 60 seconds, then try this:

```
dispatcher_Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.Fromseconds(30);

dispatcher_Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tickon);

dispatcher_Timer.Start();

private void dispatcherTimer_Tickon(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dispatcher_Timer.Tick -= new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tickon);
    // Do the work for 30 seconds and pause it using stop             
    dispatcher_Timer.Stop();

    dispatcher_Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer2_Tickon);
    dispatcher_Timer.Start();
}

private void dispatcherTimer2_Tickon(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dispatcher_Timer.Tick -= new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer2_Tickon);
    // Do the remaining work for 30 seconds and pause it using stop             
    dispatcher_Timer.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pause the timer and later have it continue where it left off. IsEnabled simply 
calls Start and Stop.

You would need to create your own timer to have this functionality.

Comment: I don't think it does that, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163300/what-is-the-different-between-isenabled-and-start-stop-of-dispatchertimer

Comment: I don't think he is correct in that post. If you look at the source for DispatchTimer, isEnabled just calls Start and Stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pause the Dispatcher by this simple trick, what if you set the time interval to zero?

**This will Pause the dispatcher**

```
 dispatcherTimer.Interval.Subtract(dispatcherTimer.Interval);
```

Again resuming the dispatchTimer is by just adding timespan to Interval.

```
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5); // this will
```

**OR**

```
dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```cs
public class DispatcherTimerEx : DispatcherTimer
{
    public new TimeSpan Interval
    {
        get => maxInterval;
        set => base.Interval = maxInterval = value;
    }

    public new bool IsEnabled
    {
        get => base.IsEnabled;
        set
        {
            if (value == base.IsEnabled)
                return;
            if (value)
                this.Start();
            else
                this.Stop();
        }
    }

    TimeSpan maxInterval;
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.MinValue;
    DateTime stopTime = DateTime.MinValue;

    public DispatcherTimerEx()
    {
        base.Tick += OnTick;
    }

    public DispatcherTimerEx(DispatcherPriority priority) : base(priority)
    {
        base.Tick += OnTick;
    }

    public DispatcherTimerEx(DispatcherPriority priority, Dispatcher dispatcher) : base(priority, dispatcher)
    {
        base.Tick += OnTick;
    }

    public DispatcherTimerEx(TimeSpan interval, DispatcherPriority priority, EventHandler callback,
        Dispatcher dispatcher) : base(interval, priority, callback, dispatcher)
    {
        base.Tick += OnTick;
    }

    public new void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        startTime = DateTime.Now;
        stopTime = DateTime.MinValue;
    }

    void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        startTime = DateTime.Now;
        if (base.Interval == maxInterval) return;

        base.Stop();
        base.Interval = maxInterval;
        base.Start();
    }


    public void Pause()
    {
        base.Stop();
        stopTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        if (startTime == DateTime.MinValue)
            startTime = DateTime.Now;

        if (stopTime == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            base.Interval = maxInterval;
        }
        else
        {
            base.Interval = maxInterval - (stopTime - startTime);
            stopTime = DateTime.MinValue;
        }

        base.Start();
    }
}
```

I added here `Puase()` and `Resume()` methods.