# WPF DispatcherTimer doesn't keep time when resumed

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

When you set in a DispatcherTimer the property IsEnabled to false, it is supposed that the timer keeps its state in the background or instead it is stopped and reset? In the following example, with a timer interval of 5s, if you run the application and if you click the button to disable the timer at 4s, and if you click again the button to enable it at 7s (for example), the timer event is not fired one second later at 8s, instead is fired at 12s = 7s + 5s. It seems that timer.IsEnabled=false resets the timer interval. There is any alternative keeping the timer state when disabled?

The application has two labels timerLabel and statusLabel and the button. I haven't enough reputation points here to post images.

```
namespace WpfApplication1 {

public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int ticksCounter = 0;  

    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer;

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5, 0);  // Sets 5 s. interval
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ticksCounter ++;
        timeLabel.Content = "Ticks = " + ticksCounter.ToString();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        if (timer.IsEnabled) {
            timer.IsEnabled = false;
            statusLabel.Content = "OFF";
            boton.Content = "Enable";
        }
        else {
            timer.IsEnabled = true;
            statusLabel.Content = "ON";
            boton.Content = "Disable";
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.Stop()`?

Comment: This answer should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163300/what-is-the-different-between-isenabled-and-start-stop-of-dispatchertimer

Comment: That answer seems to be wrong. IsEnabled=true reset the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DispatcherTimer` always starts timing anew when restarted, whether by calling `Start()` or setting `IsEnabled` to `true`. If you want the timer to resume from the middle of an interval, you'll need to implement that yourself. For example, by maintaining a `Stopwatch` to measure the elapsed time since the most recent tick and subtract that for the first interval when you restart it, restoring the interval to the desired regular interval in the `Tick` event handler.

Here's a code example that illustrates the basic idea:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
    }

    void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Interval = _baseInterval;
        _stopWatch.Restart();
    }

    private TimeSpan _baseInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    private DispatcherTimer _timer;
    private Stopwatch _stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

    // Call from appropriate location to toggle timer, e.g. in a button's
    // Click event handler.
    private void ToggleTimer()
    {
        if (_timer.IsEnabled)
        {
            _timer.IsEnabled = false;
            _stopWatch.Stop();
            button1.Content = "Start";
        }
        else
        {
            _timer.Interval = _baseInterval - _stopWatch.Elapsed;
            _stopWatch.Restart();
            _timer.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The Stopwatch addition solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know its long time passed but I was using this example and notice that to make it right you need 1 small change.

In **ToogleTimer()** function instead of calling _stopWatch.**Restart()** call _stopWatch.**Start()**.

Difference is that in code above there will be side effect if you pause more times inside 1 interval as every time you resume stopwatch is reseted (it should be reset only inside Tick event of dispathcer).